# Equivalent of onAttachedToWindow()/onDetachedFromWindow() for a ViewHolder in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm converting a bunch of Views to use the ViewHolder pattern in RecyclerView instead. I have code that needs to be run in onAttachedToWindow() and onDetachedFromWindow(), or whatever's closest to it in terms of the View lifecycle. What can I do to replicate that?

Comment: Are you looking for onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ItemBridgeAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

We can implement `View.OnAttachStateChangeListener` in our `ViewHolder`:

```
class SomeViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {

    ...

    init {
         itemView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) {
        // Do what you need
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {
        // Do what you need
    }
}
```

In `Adapter` we set view in `onCreateViewHolder(...)`:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SomeViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.some_item, parent, false)
    return SomeViewHolder(view)
}
```